# Unexpected behaviour of plotly arrowhead on annotation

Tags: javascript, plotly

When defining the arrow end type of an annotation in Plotly, if I set `arrowside: 'start'`, it seems to ignore the arrowhead setting.
Below is the annotation code, and an example on [codepen](https://codepen.io/drypatrick/pen/GRwOOEB) where I duplicated the annotation, and only changed `arrowside: "start"`.

```
var arrowhead = 7;
var annotations: [
    {
      x: 2,
      y: 5,
      xref: 'x',
      yref: 'y',
      text: 'If arrowside in set to start, the arrowhead seams to be ignored',
      showarrow: true,
      arrowhead: arrowhead,
      arrowside: "start",
      ax: 0,
      ay: -40
    },
    {
      x: 2,
      y: 3,
      xref: 'x',
      yref: 'y',
      text: 'If arrowside is omit or is set to end it work as expected',
      showarrow: true,
      arrowhead: arrowhead,
      arrowside: "end",
      ax: 0,
      ay: -40
    }
  ]
```

Am I doing something wrong, or is it a library bug?

Thank you!

Comment: TIL it seems that the arrow head for the `"start"` case should be set through [`startarrowhead`](https://plotly.com/javascript/reference/layout/annotations/#layout-annotations-items-annotation-startarrowhead) - I found out by trying to localise in the source code what I thought was a bug

Comment: I've updated the codepen, and `startarrowhead` seams to solve the issue, thanks!

Comment: @kikon if you would like to post the comment as an answer I will mark it as approved!

Comment: I think it's OK as a comment for me (I don't have time to elaborate), but if you think it would be valuable for others, feel free to answer yourself with details.

Answer (score 0):

You can define the kind of arrowhead displayed by giving an integer (0-7). The default arrowhead is "0", which turns out to be no shape at all for "end". Strangely enough there doesn't seem to be any choice in "start" type.
Can you check if defining the arrowhead solves this issue for you as well? (I'm doing this in Python, but the Plotly engine is JS in both cases)

```
showarrow: true,
arrowside: "end",
arrowhead: 1,
```

Here I plotted all combinations:

[image: Arrow conbinations]

Comment: The problem is related to the start of the arrow, wich seams to be insensible to the setting. As suggested from @kikon, it can be used the specific setting `startarrowhead`